# Some HTML presentations created using nbconvert from notebooks are not showing Plotly plots

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter-lab

I'm using Plotly inside a notebook.

I have this in one of my cells.

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
from plotly.offline import get_plotlyjs
Javascript(get_plotlyjs())
```

I load data and run Plotly in another cell. The plots show in the notebook. I save the notebook and run this from the command line.

```
jupyter nbconvert notbook.ipynb --to slides --no-prompt --embed-images
```

For some notebooks, I'm seeing the plots embedded in the HTML. For other notebooks, they are missing.

When the notebooks are missing, I'm seeing this error:

```
python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/filters/widgetsdatatypefilter.py:69: UserWarning: Your element with mimetype(s) dict_keys(['application/vnd.plotly.v1+json']) is not able to be represented.
  warn("Your element with mimetype(s) {mimetypes}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from running the notebook inside VS Code.

Running the notebook in jupyter lab and then saving it solves the problem. You can now run `jupyter nbconvert` and create an HTML presentation with plots.